# generate dynamic html pages and store in mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

im doing one simple project for an advertisement agent in php. in that when the admin upload the name,images and description of the product the data need to store in mysql(completed) and a html page need to create for that particular product in that html page the data which is inserted into the database of that particular product need to display. Is that possible? Any refference is there...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried so far? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, strangely that is possible. Seach on Google for a cms ( Content Management System such as Drupal, Wordpress etc etc etc

Comment: You can try [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog),wherein you can display the data of a table by exporting it in HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to display to the user, you can do the task via `PHP`. Get data from `mysql` via `PHP` & display it to the user. Why creating the separate HTML page!

Comment: that is the requirement from client side

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Possible.
Upload Product image on the server and store images link, name and description in MySQL Table. 
In your php script make connection to the database and fetch the data in your php script. After display the data as you want.

[PHP CRUD Tutorial (part 1)](http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1)

[File Upload and View With PHP and MySQL](http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/file-upload-and-view-with-php-and-mysql.html)